# issue with using both fetch_array and fetch_assoc on one sql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fetch

I am trying to fetch order data from order table with its id number and show only fields which are not empty in a table. Above that, I want to show the contact details of the order pulled from the users table  with username grabbed from the order table.

I considered using JOIN in the query but was getting confused as to how to display only the non empty fields of order form in a table and the contact details from users above as simple text in lines one below the other.

Finally I came up with the code below

```
if(isset($_POST['subsorder']))
    {
        include('../conn.php');
        $ordt="";
        if($sql=$orderdb->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id='$_POST[sorder]'") or die($orderdb->error))
        {
            if($sql->num_rows!=0)
            {           
                $info=$sql->fetch_assoc();
                $un=$info['username'];

                $h = "";
                $d="";
                while($row = $sql->fetch_array())
                {
                    foreach($row as $key => $value)
                    {
                        if($key != 'id' && !is_numeric($key) && $value != 0)
                        {
                            $h.= "<th>$key</th>";
                            $d.= "<td>$value</td>";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }   

            if($sql2=$usersdb->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$un'") or die($usersdb->error))
            $info2=$sql2->fetch_assoc();
            echo $info2['firstname']." ".$info2['firstname']."<br>";
            echo $info2['address1']."<br>".$info2['address2']."<br>".$info2['address2']."<br>";
            echo $info2['phone']."<br>".$info2['email']."<br>";

            echo "<table border='1' style='border-collapse:collapse'>
            <tr>$h</tr>
            <tr>$d</tr>
            </table>";
        }
    }
```

But this is creating a problem. This echoes only the contact details derived from the **info2** result set. not the table below derived from **$row** result set. But if I remove the **info** result set at the beginning, from the code, then table is shown ! But I will have to have the **info** result set because that pulls the username for use in the next query.

I am wondering whether having two fetch function on one query is the problem. Or I don't know if i have made some oversight or whether basically this usage is wrong.

Comment: SQL injection vulnerability spotted. Use prepared statements, or bobby tables will [have a field day](http://bobby-tables.com/). `$orderdb->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id='$_POST[sorder]'")` <-- what if `$_POST['sorder']` is set to `x' OR '1' = '1`?

Comment: Sure @EliasVanOotegem. Thanks for the alert. Will def do that. I am still in the initial stages. Once a working code is achieved, I will be applying myself to the security aspects like prepared statements as you suggested.

Comment: *But if I remove the info result set at the beginning, from the code, then table is shown*, how did you get `$un` in this case?

Comment: Every `fetch` moves internal result cursor to the next row. BTW the first query seems to return only one record every time, is that so? If yes, You only need to do `foreach ($info as $key => $value)` without looping through the result rows, because there is only one result row.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul That is the problem....but with that query on, contact details are displayed but  the table disappears

Comment: Ok @RomanHocke ... that was good info about the cursor moving to next row on every fetch ! Yes, there is only one row that will be returned from either table. And yes, i think I should get the fetch array out. let me check that.

Comment: @RomanHocke, you nailed it ! Removing while loop of fetch_array did it ! And the info about the cursor moving to next row for every fetch, is precious ! Thanks a ton. Please move your comment to the answer. So that I can accept it and upvote it. Thanks a ton !

Comment: @user3526204 One last note, why do you have two different connection handlers here, `$orderdb` and `$usersdb`? One connection handler is enough to repeatedly query the database.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul The reason is, the user name and contact details are in a different database than the order details.